# If $A+B+C=\frac {\pi}{2}$ then prove that....

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=\frac {\pi}{2}$ thrn prove that:$$\tan (A+B) [\tan A-\tan B]=\sqrt {1+\cot^2 C} (\sec A\cos B-\cos A\sec B)$$

My attempt

Here, $$A+B+C=\frac {\pi}{2}$$
$$A+B=\frac {\pi}{2} - C$$

Now,
$$L.H.S.=\tan(A+B) [\tan A-\tan B]
= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - C\right) \left(\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} - \frac{\sin B }{\cos B} \right)$$

$$=\cot C \frac{\sin (A-B)}{\cos A \cos B}$$
now, plz help me to continue from here.

Comment: $\sqrt {1+\cot^2 C} = \sqrt {\dfrac {\sin^2 C + \cos^2}{\sin^2}} = \sqrt {\dfrac {1}{\sin^2 C}} = \dfrac {1}{\sin C} = \dfrac {1}{\cos (A + B)}$

Comment: @Carser, what's wrong with the denominator?

Comment: @user354073 Oh there was a missing denominator when I made the comment.  It has been edited since.

Comment: @Carser, thanks for commenting.

Comment: #Mick, I.could not get your hint. Please eleborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\cot C \frac{\sin (A-B)}{\cos A \cos B} &= \frac{\cos C}{\sin C}\frac{\sin (A-B)}{\cos A \cos B} \\
&= \frac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A+B)}\frac{\sin (A-B)}{\cos A \cos B} \\
&=\frac{\frac{\cos 2B - \cos 2A}{2}}{\sin C(\cos A \cos B)}\\
&= \frac{\cos^2 B - \cos^2 A}{\sin C \cos A \cos B}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin C}(\sec A\cos B-\cos A\sec B)\\
&= \text{cosec }C(\sec A\cos B-\cos A\sec B)\\
&= \sqrt{1+\cot^2 C}(\sec A\cos B-\cos A\sec B)
\end{align*}